# How to skip bean transformation in StaxEventItemReader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'd like to use `spring-batch` for processing xml files.
There is already a `StaxEventItemReader` for parsing.

Problem: the reader requires a `Bean` object that is created for each record in the xml.

Example from 
https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-batch-examples/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/net/petrikainulainen/springbatch/xml/in/XmlFileToDatabaseJobConfig.java

```
    @Bean
    ItemReader<StudentDTO> xmlFileItemReader(Environment environment) {
        StaxEventItemReader<StudentDTO> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_XML_SOURCE_FILE_PATH)));
        xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("student");

        Jaxb2Marshaller studentMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        studentMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(StudentDTO.class);

        xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(studentMarshaller);
        return xmlFileReader;
    }
```

Question: how can I tell the reader to *not* parse to a bean, but just output a flat csv from each record, without having to transform to a bean prior?

Regarding the example, I want to skip `StudentDTO` objects creation, and just get the plain values from the reader as eg csv or list.

Comment: You could use a `Map` as the return type, but the parsed XML must be converted into something...

Comment: Could I use a `StringBuilder` somehow and append the content on it?

Comment: @membersound Have you fixed the issue, I want to ignore one filed from the  file reading, please help me on it